# How to fix some coefficient in sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am running logistic regression sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression. Say I have 3 features in my model A, B and C. I want to fix the coefficient of A but want sklearn to estimate the coefficient of B and C to minimize the logloss. I know I can do this in R pretty easily using offset(), but not sure how to do this in sklearn?

Context: I am doing a causal analysis where I have estimated the coefficient of A using a separate instrumental variable approach. Now I want to also estimate coefficient and B and C for predictive purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to do this with `sklearn` directly, but you can accomplish this in Python with a GLM from `statsmodels`. You can find the documentation [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.html). The interface is a little different than an `sklearn`-style estimator, but you can build a thin wrapper. A simple example is something like:

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from statsmodels.api import GLM, families

class LogisticRegressionWithOffset(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y, offset=None):
        self.offset = offset
        self.fitted = GLM(y, X, family=families.Binomial(), offset=offset).fit()
        return self

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        p = self.fitted.predict(X, offset=self.offset).reshape(-1, 1)
        return np.concatenate([1 - p, p], axis=1)

    def predict(self, X):
        return 1*(self.predict_proba(X)[:,1]>0.5)
```